# Java - Highlight parts of an image

Tags: java, image-manipulation

I'm using an image of a dart board in this example as it's a good example for what I am trying to achieve.

Is there any way in Java that part of an image can be highlighted? I achieved the below by using the `Magic Wand` in Paint.NET and added an outline to the selected part.

The 'problem' here is if I wanted to highlight every part of this dart board individually, I'm going to end up with a lot of pictures.

Is there some clever library out there that can do this programmatically so I have literally just the one image and can somehow point to some coordinates, it imitates the "magic wand" effect and adds an outline of my choice?

Without highlight:

[image: Without highlight]

With highlight:

[image: With highlight]

Thanks,
Ricky

**Edit**: Answer taken for simplicity. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just rotate the highlight image around for each position of the dartboard? Is this a Swing app? Java2D? What framework do you use?

Comment: Ah, clever. Didn't think of that. Thanks. I will see what other suggestions come up, part this sounds like a good idea.

Comment: That, or just draw the outline with Java2D.

Comment: It's going to be an app for Android (1.6+). I am now looking into Java2D but what attracts me to your idea is the ease of the solution. Edit: Also the app will be a static image with just parts highlighted, nothing more.

Comment: Ah, if is for Android you could use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html for convenience